# is there a way to avoid the parallelism grant warning for the first azure pipeline?

Tags: azure

I've used Azure for a few years but this is my first time using Azure Pipelines.  Today I created a basic pipeline from a wizard in Azure DevOps.  When I ran the pipeline it encountered an error regarding the need for a parallelism grant.

The error message was provided through a url where I was required to submit a request to msft for parallelism and apparently it takes Microsoft 2-3 days to approve the request.  So is there a way for me to avoid this error message when I run my first pipeline in a new Azure instance?

Based on the semantics of the error message, sounds like parallelism support is needed to run 2 pipelines at the same time - or maybe 2 concurrent tasks within a single pipeline at the same time.  I don't require either of these capabilities for the pipeline that I need to run.  I only have a single pipeline so it seems like there may be concurrent tasks configured within that pipeline but I just created a default pipeline from the Azure DevOps wizard.

Can you please provide some guidance on this?  Not sure if parallelism capability is needed to support the core functionality of Azure pipelines or if is there are any types of configurations, settings or keywords that I can use to effectively sidestep this blocker

Comment: Earlier Azure DevOps pipelines where given as a free tier similar to the Azure Free Trial subscription, But in order to increase the security, Now its mandatory to raise a request for Hosted parallelism grant by filling this form -https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR63mUWPlq7NEsFZhkyH8jChUMlM3QzdDMFZOMkVBWU5BWFM3SDI2QlRBSC4u

Comment: Also, Refer here We have temporarily disabled the free grant of parallel jobs for public projects and for certain private projects in new organizations. However, you can request this grant by submitting a request. Existing organizations and projects are not affected. Please note that it takes us 2-3 business days to respond to your free tier requests. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted

Comment: After you raise a request and it is accepted you will be granted a 1 parallel job with Microsoft hosted agent Free Tier grant and you can run your pipelines, Refer here - https://i.imgur.com/j97rjxQ.png and after that you can run pipelines refer here -https://i.imgur.com/soj1xDZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary building block in an Azure DevOps pipeline is a [Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps?view=azure-pipelines), every Step whether you specify or not is enclosed inside a [Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

One job may have multiple step(s), each job needs to run separately on a [Build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) (Microsoft hosted / self-hosted), each build agent belongs to an Agent Pool

I would suggest you to go over the [Key concepts for new Azure Pipelines users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops)

[image]

> Based on the semantics of the error message, sounds like parallelism
> support is needed to run 2 pipelines at the same time - or maybe 2
> concurrent tasks within a single pipeline at the same time

Assuming that you are already running your pipeline (specifically a Job) on a Microsoft hosted agent, to ensure the "parallelism" of the jobs, you need to submit a request as suggested by the message and once that is approved you would be able to run your pipelines normally.

If you still wish to run the pipeline while waiting for the approval you can setup your own [agent pool (self-hosted)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) which could be your own local machine to run the pipeline.